# Vscode: Unable to load schema from 'https://json.schemastore.org/gitlab-ci': getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND json.schemastore.org.(768)

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, continuous-integration, gitlab, yaml

I am trying to edit GitLab YAML file in vscode but get to see below error.

```
Unable to load schema from 'https://json.schemastore.org/gitlab-ci': getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND json.schemastore.org.(768)
```

Here is the screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1):

GitLab's schema is no longer stored at `'https://json.schemastore.org/gitlab-ci'`

In order to have VSCode load the schema properly, add this to your `.vscode/settings.json` file:

```yaml
   "yaml.schemas": {
        "https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/raw/master/app/assets/javascripts/editor/schema/ci.json": ".gitlab-ci.yml"
    }
```

You'll just need the [RedHat YAML Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-yaml) installed for it to work.

This was being discussed also as part of GitLab's Workflow VSCode extension, you can follow more on that issue here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-vscode-extension/-/issues/382